# How to notify user if admin didn't response within X minutes in Laravel and VueJs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building a system where an user will place an order, It will be broadcast to the admin. Admin will have X minutes to response to the user order. If admin didn't response user will be notified. What is the best approach to do it with Laravel and Vuejs ?

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of conversation between server and client I think pusher is the best way.

[Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels)

Comment: Yes I am using broadcasting service but how will user be notified after sometime if admin is not available or ignored the user order.

Comment: one way is to constantly check db from client. for example if it already exceeded X minutes.

the second way is to have cron job which let's say is scheduled per minute and every minute this cron job will execute, check if there are any expired orders and if there is you will send notification using pusher.

first requires client resources, and the second requires server resources.